# Google Maps API Referer 403 Error

Tags: google-maps

My website uses the Google maps API (3.0) in a very heavy way. I had to register my application with Google APIs Console.

In the "referers" section I put `*.websitename.com/*` (there is `*` at the start and at the end), but when I try to access maps from `http://websitename.com` it doesn't work and appear, and a Google message appears in the console saying it's unauthorized from this referrer (403 Error).

How can I write the "referers" to allow both

`http://www.websitename.com`

and

`http://websitename.com`

as referers?

Comment: Why did you add a `.` before the domainname?

Answer (score 12):

There is no single pattern that matches both cases, you must use 2 referers

```
*.websitename.com/*
websitename.com/*
```

**EDIT :**
Keep in mind that sometimes it needs 5 minutes for changes to take effect.

Comment: This is still not clear in their documentation. I expected `*websitename.com/*` to work in both cases (although someone with "someotherwebsitename.com" could theoretically use your key)

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.  It fixed my same issue (over 3 years later).