# Google does not permit the use of the Maps API for this application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good day.

Now i create api Key for browser apps (with referers).

```
Referers: *.invait.ru/*
```

But on site i get error:

```
Google does not permit the use of the Maps API for this application. 
API Google key provided is invalid or do not have permission to use it 
with Google Maps JavaScript API v3 on this site.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Tell me please why i get it error and how remove error and use google map api v3?

Comment: which referers did you define?

Comment: @Dr.Molle `Referers: *.invait.ru/*`

Comment: this referer is only valid for subdomains of invait.ru, but not for `http://invait.ru`

Comment: @Dr.Molle tell me please how right need write `referers` that api work on address `http://invait.ru/gde_kupit/` and tell me please if i remove `referers` pi will be woked on it address  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Referer Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467546/google-maps-api-referer-configuration)

Comment: When you remove the referers it works on both domains. But the key may be hijacked, so I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For domain use `Referers: invait.ru/*`