# Google api key - access denied

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Good day.
We have domain astralux.biz

We need that key worked for www.astralux.biz and astralux.biz

For this in input allowed referars we write *.astralux.biz/*

But for www.astralux.biz key worked and for astralux.biz key not worked(access denied).

Tell me please why key not worked and how write correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Referer Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467546/google-maps-api-referer-configuration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#whitelistingbyip). Add astralux.biz/* (remove the period); *.astralux.biz should match all subdomains, if you don't need that then www.astralux.biz will work for www.astralux.biz

```
astralux.biz/*
www.astralux.biz/*
```