# Google Maps API key - 403 forbidden on Streetview

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm trying to get a static streetview image, but I'm getting 403 forbidden. If I remove the `key` parameter in the query it works fine.

The query:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=584x300&location=46+Hester+Street+New+York+US&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

I'm doing the query on an https site, https://bubbl.li and my config settings on https://console.developers.google.com are:

```
REFERERS  
*.bubbl.li/*

Activated APIs
Google Maps JavaScript API v3       
ON
Static Maps API     
ON
Street View Image API       
ON
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Referer 403 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467546/google-maps-api-referer-403-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The referer `*.bubbl.li/*` doesn't permit requests from  `https://bubbl.li` , it's only valid for subdomains.

Add the referer

```
bubbl.li/*
```